# Add a new language to Thunderbird spell check

Tags: dictionary, spell-checking, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I would like to add Persian language to the Mozilla Thunderbird spell check. The [available dictionaries page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/language-tools/) does not contain my favorite language, however it is available in [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/) and [Open Office](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/persian-spellchecker-dictionary) dictionaries. The only relevant result I found [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dictionaries) does not describe how to add a dictionary to Thunderbird dictionaries page.

Could anybody tell me how I can contribute a new dictionary to Mozilla Thunderbird dictionaries as they appear in above mentioned page?

Comment: If I find it by my own for sure I will write it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should "save as" on the Firefox dictionary addon you found, and then try to add it in Thunderbird as is. ("Install addon from file").
The Firefox addon probably also contains the relevant section that will make it usable for Thunderbird.

If it doesn't work, [check this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Creating_a_spell_check_dictionary_add-on). The page also applies to Thunderbird dictionaries.

Especially, if you got a message along the lines of "this addon is not compatible with your version of Thunderbird", you can just unzip the .xpi, modify the "install.rdf" file and put an updated value in `maxVersion`. Zip back the content of the folder, rename to .xpi and try to install again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The error happened as you had mentioned. There was a problem that thunderbird did not accept the created xpi file, no mather what was the content. To solve this problem, instead of creating a new zip and renaming it, I modifed the xpi file inside Archive Manager on the fly. It worked fine.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I was compressing the folder therfore the files were not at the root of extension, instead now I compress the contents of the folder.